# augmented matrix of the system of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

can you help me check whether my attempt to the following question.

Write down the augmented matrix of the system of linear equation

```
 1w + 2x - 2y - 5z = -8
 2w + 4x - 3y - 7z = -9
 1w + 2x + 0y + 1z =  6
-1w - 2x + 1y + 2z =  1
```

here is my attempt 
an augmented matrix is written as follow : ax + by + cz + dw therefore

```
2  -2  -5  1  = -8
4  -3  -7  1  = -9
2   0   1  1  =  6
```

-2   1   2 -1  =  1

sorry for not putting it inside a large bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your second row is wrong (The coefficient of w should be 2;
2. You don't need to write in XYZW order, so it would be better to preserve original order;